# Rotate NSImageView in Swift

Tags: swift, nsimage, nsimageview

I using playground to rotate the following image.

```
 let imagePath = pathToFileInSharedSubfolder("gauge.png")
 let image = NSImage(byReferencingFile: imagePath)!


let imageView = NSImageView()
imageView.image = image

//Frames
let imageframe = imageView.frame
let origin = CGPointMake(imageframe.width/2, 0)
imageView.setFrameOrigin(origin)
imageView.rotateByAngle(35)
imageView.setNeedsDisplay()
let frame = CGRectMake(150, 0, 51, 126)
imageView.frame = frame
view.addSubview(imageView)

let refImageView = NSImageView()
refImageView.frame = frame
refImageView.image = image

view.addSubview(refImageView)
```

The image is not rotation about my origin point. See image below?

How does one change the image view origin? Thanks.

[image]